# How to fetch data from business layer using AJAX, Jquery and Spring MVC on selction of a value in a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a drop down list, from which, if I select a value an ajax call will be made to my controller and fetch a value. This will be displayed in a text box.

In my jsp I have written this code.

```
<td>
    <form:select path="designation" id="designation" onchange="getSalary();">
        <form:option value="Engineer" label="E"/>
        <form:option value="Senior Engineer" label="SE"/>
        <form:option value="Analyst" label="A"/>
        <form:option value="Lead" label="L"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
```

The javascript function is as below

```
function getSalary()
{
var element=document.getElementById("designation");
var designation = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
alert(designation);//Till this part its working

$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/SpringMVC/employee/getSalary.do",
        data:{design:designation},
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert("Inside success function");
            $('#salary').val(data);
        },
        error:function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
                if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState=0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
                    return;
        },
    });

}
```

The corresponding method in the controller class is as below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getSalary",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody double GetSalary(@RequestParam(value="design",required=true)String design, ModelMap model){
        System.out.println(design);
        double salary = 50000;
        System.out.println("Employee Controller >> Getting salary : " + salary);
        return salary;
    }

}
```

The flow is going into the javascript function. but the ajax call is not happening. The flow is breaking somewhere before reaching the controller.
I have checked the config files and they are good as other URLs can hit the controller and fetch results. only the when I am using this ajax call it is breaking.
Can someone help me identify what exactly I am doing wrong with the ajax call.

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: With javascript you never know. Did you try: data:{"design":designation}

Comment: I am getting this error in the IE console
`SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined`
But I have the jquery file loaded in the workspace with the script statement
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`